# Is it possible to store a django template tag value, like lorem, in a variable?

Tags: python, django-templates, templatetags, django-3.1

I came across a scenario where I wanted to display a fake name on a django 3.1 template.  So I used the following code:

```
Name: {% lorem 2 w random %}
```

Then I realized I had another location on my display that would contain the same name.  Of course if I use the same code again, then I would get a random different two words.

So I tried to store the value in a variable so I could have the exact same random name twice.  I am looking over a number of records and wanted random names for each record, so although this doesn't work, it is what I was trying to attempt.

```
{% for d in dict %}
    {% with lorem 2 w random as randName %}
        Name: {{ randName }}<br>
        ....<br>
        Name: {{ randName }}<br><br>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Expected Output:

```
Name: TEMPORIBUS EXERCITATIONEM
....
Name: TEMPORIBUS EXERCITATIONEM

Name: QUAM PARIATUR
....
Name: QUAM PARIATUR
```

for as many dictionary items exist. This is not a huge deal, more curiosity and wanting to better understand the django framework.  Is it possible to get a value from the lorem template tag and store it as a variable?

I have also tried creating a custom template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def setvar(val=None):
  return val
```

And on my template:

```
{% setvar randName as lorem 2 w random %}
```

but I get the error that it only expects one parameter.

Comment: Does your template tag works?

Comment: This tag {% lorem 2 w random %} alone works, but if I use it in two locations on the page I will get different random names, I was hoping to store it in a variable so I could show the exact name twice or more.  I suppose another question would be if I could call lorem from my view and loop over my dictionary and create them in the view and then I could display it twice.